# Managing count grouped by another column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset and I want to see the amount of Unique IDs go to another ID and create a new column showing the count. Here is a sample.

```
 ID     Reporting ID 
 101         103
 102         103
 103         107
 104         103 
 105         107 
 106         103 
 107         110
 108         103
 109         110 
 110
```

Desired output:

```
 ID      Reporting ID     Reporting Count 
 101          103               0
 102          103               0
 103          107               5
 104          103               0
 105          107               0
 106          103               0
 107          110               2
 108          103               0
 109          110               0
 110                            2
```

I have tried `df['Reporting Count'] = df.groupby('Reporting ID')['ID'].nunique()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you need to map the `ID` to the count:

```
counts = df.groupby('Reporting ID')['ID'].nunique()
df['Reporting Count'] =  df.ID.map(counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    ID  Reporting ID  Reporting Count
0  101         103.0                0
1  102         103.0                0
2  103         107.0                5
3  104         103.0                0
4  105         107.0                0
5  106         103.0                0
6  107         110.0                2
7  108         103.0                0
8  109         110.0                0
9  110           NaN                2
```

Comment: When I try that I get NaN from all them

Comment: Nevermind I didn't change a dataframe properly